# Timesyncd with NTP server using md5

Tags: systemd, ntp, time-synchronization, ntpd

I have a FreeBSD server used as an NTP server with md5 as authentication. 
If I want to connect to it from a FreeBSD/Linux machine which has ntpd, I can simply add something along the lines of `server 192.168.1.1 key 10` in `/etc/ntp.conf` and then specify the server sided key in `/etc/ntp/keys`.

But how would I do this on a server like Proxmox which has timesyncd?
Should I uninstall timesyncd and get ntpd. I'm not exactly sure if timesyncd allows syncing over NTP with md5.

Answer (score 2):

systemd-timesyncd is (currently) very simple and doesn't support sending authentication keys to a remote NTP server. At the time of writing, [its *only* configuration options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html) are for the addresses of the NTP servers it should contact.

Consider either syncing to public NTP servers, or securing access to your NTP servers in another way, such as with a firewall. You might also [submit a feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/new).

Comment: Still nothing.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/22664